# how can I store key and value to array storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I had stored my input on a object(key and value) using:

```
const object1 = {
    un: inp.value,
    pw: inpw.value
};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(object1);
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
```

Now I want every object to be stored in an array, for example the first input is:

> - {"un":"john","pw":"smith"}

It would be stored to `array[0]`

The second input then will be for example:

> - {"un":"beth","pw":"sebastian"}

And so on..

So when I call array[0], it will only display {"un":"john","pw":"smith"}'

So this is my code:

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on">
  <div class="" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Input" autocomplete="input">
    <input id="myPW" type="password" name="myPassword" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="password">
  </div>
  <input id="button" type="submit">
</form>

    <h2>Username</h2>
    <p id="uname"></p>

    <h2>Password</h2>
    <p id="pass"></p>

    <h2>Data</h2>
    <ol id="val"></ol>

    <h2>Array</h2>
    <ol id="arr"></ol>

<script>
var myButton = document.getElementById('button');
var inp = document.getElementById('myInput');
var inpw = document.getElementById('myPW');

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const object1 = {
        un: inp.value,
        pw: inpw.value
    };
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(object1);
    var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);

    val.innerHTML += '<li>' + myJSON + '</li>';


    //it should be in this part where it document the myJSON
    cookies = [];
    cookies.push(myJSON);
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        arr.innerHTML += '<li>' + cookies[i] + '</li>';
    }       
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what you expect?

Comment: I answered solely your question without taking into consideration the rest of your code, so I'm not sure about your usage of the `cookies` array that you're looping through, would you mind explaining what does it do and maybe I can give you a better answer depending on your actual usage/need?

Comment: I want to document or display each array to  this part <ol id="arr"></ol>; cookies array is the storage btw, for example cookies[0] = {"un":"john","pw":"smith" then cookies[1] = {"un":"beth","pw":"sebastian"} and so on in which these data are user's input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array and push the values to it :

```
var inputData = [];

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(object1);
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);

inputData.push(myObj)
```

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lya0nu1t/1/